# Syntax of Importing LogicalExpressionOracle in IBM Quantum Lab

Tags: ibm-q-experience, grovers-algorithm, programming

[This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/solving-satisfiability-problems-with-grovers-algorithm-quantum-computing-c9d6c177b966) provides a sample code to use Grover's algorithm to solve SAT problems. It requires importing a method called LogicalExpressionOracle. However, when I copied the code into IBM quantum lab, it says that qiskit.aqua doesn't exist anymore. So how can I import LogicalExpressionOracle?

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import BasicAer
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
from qiskit.aqua import QuantumInstance, run_algorithm
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import Grover
from qiskit.aqua.components.oracles import LogicalExpressionOracle, TruthTableOracle
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`PhaseOracle`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.PhaseOracle.html) from Qiskit Terra:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import PhaseOracle

oracle = PhaseOracle.from_dimacs_file("file_name.cnf")
```

Comment: How can I create a file ending with ".cnf"?

Comment: In IBM Quantum Lab click on "New file" button, and choose Text File. Then, rename it.